# Is it possible to pass a class as parameter to a mixin in Stylus?

Tags: css, stylus

I’m trying to reduce some Stylus code using its mixins.
In some particular cases I need a class as a parameter. Let’s we’ve got:

```
.parent:hover .child
   color: lighten(red, -25%)

.child
   color red
```

I’d like to have a mixin which gets both classes as parameters.

I can’t find a way from the docs. ((

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with interpolation: http://stylus-lang.com/docs/interpolation.html

Here's an example codepen: https://codepen.io/webdevdani/pen/POVLpr

Code example from codepen:

```css
/* Stylus */

.box {
 height: 2rem;
 width: @height;
 background-color: blue;
 padding: 1rem;
}

.red-box {
 background-color: red;
}

$blockColor(parentClass, childClass) {
 {parentClass} {
  background-color: green;
  
  {childClass} {
   background-color: yellow;
  }
 }
} 
  
$blockColor('.box', '.red-box');
```

```html
<div class="box">
 <div class="box red-box"></div>
</div>
```